# On the superjet conception of Crandall, Ishii and Lions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

In the "User's guide to viscosity solutions" by Crandall, Ishii and Lions, they proposed the following notion:

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The superjet of $\varphi$ at $\bar{x}$ is defined by
$$
\small J^{2,+}\varphi(\bar{x}):=\left\{(p,A)\in\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{S}^n:\limsup_{x\rightarrow\bar{x}}\frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(\bar{x})-\langle x^*,x-\bar{x}\rangle-\frac{1}{2}\langle A(x-\bar{x}),x-\bar{x}\rangle}{\|x-\bar{x}\|^2}\leq 0\right\},
$$
where $\mathbb{S}^n$ is the set of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

They made the following claim as an interesting exercise:
$$
 J^{2,+}\varphi(\bar{x})=\left\{(\nabla s(\bar{x}),\nabla^2s(\bar{x})):s \;\text{is}\;C^2\;\text{and}\;\varphi-s\;\text{has a local maximum at}\;\bar{x}\right\}.
$$
I have tried without success to prove this claim and would appreciate some help.
Moreover I would like to ask whether or not
$$
 J^{2,+}\varphi(\bar{x})=\left\{(\nabla s(\bar{x}),\nabla^2s(\bar{x})):s \;\text{is convex,}\;C^2\;\text{and}\;\varphi-s\;\text{has a local maximum at}\;\bar{x}\right\}.
$$

Comment: It's not true. Compute the superjet for $\phi(x)=-|x|^2$ for both versions.

Comment: Could you make clear your comment?

Comment: I mean you cannot assume $s$ is convex in your version (unless $\phi$ happens to be convex.)